# Is there a way to run the mesa compiler to reduce the size of shader files?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, glsl

The mesa drivers, as part of their compilation process, reduce the size of the glsl shader files.

Some libraries, like [this one](https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer), use this fact to create shader minification libraries. All minification libraries I have found are abandonware, so, unless mesa has functionality to get the intermediary glsl files directly, I may have to edit the actual code the way those libraries did it.

I was wondering if there is an executable within the mesa code base that can be used to do the stripping without having to edit the code.

I tried reading the official mesa documentation, but I didn't anything that suggests either way:
https://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html

Comment: Might see what [Mesa's stand-alone compiler](https://www.mesa3d.org/shading.html#standalone) outputs with the `--dump-builder` option.

Comment: Nope, that option is not very useful, sorry :(

Comment: "*Some libraries, like this one, use this fact to create shader minification libraries.*" According to the documentation, the library *optimizes* the shader in some way. It may be that the shader text happens to get shorter, but that's not the goal. The impetus for the library, as stated on that site, is "quite a few mobile platforms are pretty bad at optimizing shaders ... So using a GLSL optimizer offline before can make the shader run much faster". That has nothing to do with the size of the shader. So are you asking about size changing or performance optimization?

Comment: I am asking about size changing.

Comment: @Makogan: My point is that "size changing" is not what those tools do. That *may happen* along the way, but that's not the point of them. It's like buying an automobile for its ability to produce carbon dioxide; yes, some of them do that, but that's not why you get one.

Comment: Perhaps, but if all the market has as tools to make Co2 is cars, I am stuck trying to pick the one that produces the most.

Comment: Not sure what your platform target is, but something like compiling to SPIRV binaries, and then use SPIRV-Cross on the target device to spit things back out as GLSL might work? That said SPIRV isn't know for being the most compact binary format in the world.

Comment: SPIRV can potentially be bigger than GLSL actually,  worse glslang does not supportOpenGL ES 2, so you cant spirvify most webgl shaders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Minification" is something different to optimization. Typically the term is used to describe a process that takes a source file in text form and removes all superfluous whitespace and replaces all identifiers with shorter ones.

Strictly speaking the whole idea of minification is a folly, since it has zero impact on performance; neither lexing the code, nor the compilation result are affected by it. The whole minification doofus started in web development to reduce webpage resource size; totally worthless, because you'll get far better performance if you just compress the text with gzip or similar. Heck after zipping the original and the minified versions' sized will probably within a few bytes of each other.

If you're really concerned about the size of your shader as a resource, just compress it (but mind the overhead of the decompression code). *EDIT: However if your target is WebGL, then make use of HTTP transport gzip compression. The relevant browsers do support it all, and most HTTP servers can be configured to transparently deliver a supplementary `.gz` suffixed file (or do the compression and cache it on the fly).*

For optimization, you should look to the other offerings of Khronos. Specifically the GLSL to SPIR-V compiler `glslc`, the SPIR-V optimizer `spirv-opt`, and the SPIR-V decompiler `spirv-cross`. You can chain those up to create optimized, "reduced" GLSL.

```
glslc --target-env=opengl -fshader-stage=... -o ${FILE}.spv ${FILE}
spirv-opt -Os -o ${FILE}.spv.opt ${FILE}.spv
spirv-cross --output ${FILE}.opt ${FILE}.spv.opt
```

Since the SPIR-V tools are part of the official Vulkan SDK, and SPIR-V is also a valid shader format to be loaded directly by OpenGL-4.6 (instead of just GLSL source), you can sleep well on the fact, that these tools are well maintained and will also be so in the future.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but, as is often the case, the question isn't "Should I do this" the question is "How do I achieve this". In other words, you can give me a well written explanation on how the world could potentially end if I did this and I would still try to do it. I am not in control of my requirements, so I have to do what I was asked to do. And that is, to reduce GLSL storage size.

Comment: @Makogan: But I did. I gave you the exact command lines to use, to 1) compile GLSL to SPIR-V, then 2) have the SPIR-V optimizes and finally 3) transpiled back into GLSL.